# Check does url containt some word in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have an URL that goes something like this `http://www.dev.example.com` and some URL that is like this `http://www.test.example.com`.

I dont know where dev and test word would be, maybe on the end maybe, on beggining. What i need to do is to check does url has some word and do something , her is something i need

```
var test = "test";
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri **have** test)
{
   /// Do something
}
```

Comment: Use `.Contains("test")` . If you want case-insensitive search, then use   `.Contains("test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: @JLevett: That was a typo error, you should concentrate on the asked query rather than typo mistakes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try this

```
var test = "test";

 if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(test))
{
   /// Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = "test";
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(test))
{
   /// Do something
}
```

Comment: @JLevett: Dear that's a typo error and this website is for explaining the copcepts not the exact syntax. And if someone knows the language, then he/she can understand.